# Cydia Impactor won't sideload

Tags: ios, install, jailbreak, certificate, cydia

When I try to sign/resign (sideload) H3lix-RC5.ipa (iPhone 5C w/ iOS 10.3.3 x32) or g0blin_rc2.ipa (iPhone 6S w/ iOS 10.3.3 x64) I get:

```
Error:
file: installation.cpp; line: 42; what:

Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xVJ2U0/extracted/Payload/g0blin.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
```

or:

```
Error:
file: installation.cpp; line: 42; what:

Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.cW2DjU/extracted/Payload/h3lix.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
```

I have tried revoking all Xcode certificates and changing Info.plist's MinimumOSVersion value.

I originally revoked all certificates because I was getting `You already have a current iOS Development certificate or a pending certificate request` when attempting to sideload.

The iPhone 6S is semi-jailbroken, and sideloading `g0blin` is the only way to semi-jailbreak it, where with the iPhone 5C the only way of jailbreaking it is by sideloading `H3lix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s bug in the Apple’s servers so you could use totally not spyware jailbreak.

g0blin is not the only way to jailbreak at iOS 10.3.3. There are doubleH3lix which is developed by tihmstar (same person made H3lix too).

Also there is website called https://totally-not.spyware.lol/ can enable you to jailbreak without sideloading app.

Comment: I know, and have used both of those jailbreak methods, but my phone has to be semi-jailbroken only g0blin offers that

Comment: What do you mean by semi-jailbreak @sam

Comment: Basically no tweaks (jailbroken while holding power and volume up button)

Comment: @Sam jailbroken state without any tweaks injecting? It could be safe mode. Is it?

Comment: Basically, though it turns out that doubleH3lix offers that too

Comment: It is featured in Cydia Substrate so all jailbreaks have one.

Comment: Even totaly-not.spyware.lol?

Comment: @Sam I guess it has too, can i ask why you want substrate mode?

Comment: Whenever I jailbreak it, while respringing it gets stuck, resprings and gets stuck two more times, and then restarts.

Comment: @Sam did you checked your tweaks? Sounds like you got one which is not compatible.

Comment: Well, I know that I have some old ones that used to work on my phone (same iOS), and to add to the confusion, a couple of days ago I disabled all tweaks with iCleaner, installed the update for it, and now it won't open. Also, whenever I try to (install, update, remove) anything on Cydia it tries (and fails) to install KarenLocalizer. https://imgur.com/a/uNcOEff

Comment: KarenLocalizer is dependency for Appsync Unified which Cydia trying to upgrade. Also you are trying to download KarenLocalizer from hackyouriphone which hosts pirated tweaks. You could try removing hackyouriphone repo or download KarenLocalizer from bigboss.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I already have KarenLocalizer installed, and it tries to install whenever I install, upgrade, or remove anything. I was just using Appsync as an example. https://imgur.com/a/GNF8R74

Comment: Do you got Filza installed?

Comment: No, I use Fily and FileBrowser

Comment: remove "libkarenlocalizer.dylib" which can be found on /usr/lib/

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JfgP58I.jpg "libkarenlocalizer.dylib" can't be deleted

Comment: Trying with terminal

Comment: Deleted (and backed up), now what?

Comment: Try to uninstall or install some tweaks.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/W66dZT1

Comment: It's not on bigboss, only on Hyi for me

Comment: @Sam Try to refresh repos 1-2 times. It is on bigboss.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Sam sometimes Cydia fails to retrieve tweaks from repos. You can refresh repos at “Sources” tab.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91092/discussion-on-answer-by-emirhan-cydia-impactor-wont-sideload).

Answer (score 0):

There are some certification issues with Apple/Xcode, perhaps that is the reason.

Postpone it for a day or two

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132628/provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-acc

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue I have as well. Started on g0blin however when I try and use totallynotspyware or DoubH3lix JB, it tells me my device is already jailbroken.. Even though I lost my G0blin icon as well as its listing in Device Management.. My only options are to either use G0blin to re-jailbreak, or format and then use Meridian.. Bottomline, once you use one method, you stuck on that method unless you do a complete wipe is what I'm seeing.. I don't think a lot of people realize that. I'm only basing this off my device not being about to be re-jailbroken and getting the error message I mentioned earlier. So for us JB users who lost our jailbreaks, our only option may be to hope and wait until the Apple server issue is resolved, or hope that Saurik can come up with a update of some sort for Impactor so we can get back to JB business. Otherwise you have to format your OS and start from scratch.. Which sucks for me because I use alot of tweaks and repos. This is one of the reasons why I wont give up on my ios 9.0 device even though its severely out of date.. Cause I stay on full jailbreak even if my battery dies.

Comment: Are you using totaly-not.spyware.lol or meridian? Also, I use all three methods (doubleH3lix, totally-not.spyware.lol, g0blin) side by side and have never had any issues